# How to authenticate google api to insert calendar events - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

How can I authenticate my api access to insert new events to my google calendar without OAuth? I'm writing a node script without any front end/website and everywhere seems to recommend using OAuth with a redirect to your website...

The best solution I have come up with is write a secondary application purely to listen for that redirect and save the auth code returned.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think it was designed that OAuth be used to handle authentication and authorization when you're using Google APIs. You can read that from the [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

> Google APIs use the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authentication and
>   authorization. Google supports common OAuth 2.0 scenarios such as
>   those for web server, installed, and client-side applications.

If you're using NodeJS for Calendar API, you can try the [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs). You'll be needing the following:

> 1. Node.js installed.
> 2. The npm package management tool (comes with Node.js).
> 3. Access to the internet and a web browser.
> 4. A Google account with Google Calendar enabled.